# select count(*) runs into timeout issues in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Maybe it is a stupid question, but I'm not able to determine the size of a table in Cassandra.

This is what I tried:

`select count(*) from articles;`

It works fine if the table is small but once it fills up, I always run into timeout issues:

cqlsh:

- OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1

DBeaver:

- Run 1: 225,000 (7477 ms)
- Run 2: 233,637 (8265 ms)
- Run 3: 216,595 (7269 ms)

I assume that it hits some timeout and just aborts. The actual number of entries in the table is probably much higher.

I'm testing against a local Cassandra instance which is completely idle. I would not mind if it has to do a full table scan and is unresponsive during that time.

**Is there a way to reliably count the number of entries in a Cassandra table?**

I'm using Cassandra 2.1.13.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I see you problem connected to timeout of **cqlsh**: OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1

you can simple increase it with options:

```
 --connect-timeout=CONNECT_TIMEOUT
                       Specify the connection timeout in seconds (default: 5
                       seconds).
 --request-timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT
                       Specify the default request timeout in seconds
                       (default: 10 seconds).
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, with an increased timeout, SELECT returns the expected number of elements.

Comment: Increasing both timeouts didn't work for me :/ I set both to 100 seconds, but `cqlsh` failed after 16 seconds with `ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses]`. Using `COPY TO` per [@PhilippClaßen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745042/1727828) was the only way I could compute the row count.

Comment: Increasing both timeouts did not work for me either. I also used COPY tablename TO '/dev/null'; to get the count. Maybe there is specific format for providing --connect-timeout and --request-timeout?

Answer (score 23):

Here is my current workaround:

```
COPY articles TO '/dev/null';
...
3568068 rows exported to 1 files in 2 minutes and 16.606 seconds.
```

---

Background: Cassandra supports to
[export a table to a text file](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra), for instance:

```
COPY articles TO '/tmp/data.csv';
Output: 3568068 rows exported to 1 files in 2 minutes and 25.559 seconds
```

That also matches the number of lines in the generated file:

```
$ wc -l /tmp/data.csv
3568068
```

Comment: The COPY command is essentially doing a full cluster scan like COUNT(*) would, and this solution will not scale either. Like others have mentioned you'll have to settle for an approx row count to maintain speed and stability in your cluster. Options are. Counter columns, hyperloglog, or reading your tables metadata will give you and estimate of how many partitions there are.

Comment: I'm OK with sacrificing scalability, as my intention was only to understand what is going on in my local development environment. I agree that it is not a solution that can be used in production.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to reliably count the number of entries in a Cassandra table?

Plain answer is **no**. It is not a **Cassandra** limitation but a hard challenge for **distributed systems** to count unique items reliably.

That's the challenge that approximation algorithms like **HyperLogLog** address.

One possible solution is to use **counter** in Cassandra to count the number of distinct rows but even **counters** can miscount in some corner cases so you'll get a few % error.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good utility for counting rows that avoids the timeout issues that happen when running a large `COUNT(*)` in Cassandra:

https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-count

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple:

When you're using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM articles;
```

it has the same effect on the database as:

```
SELECT * FROM articles;
```

You have to query over all your nodes. Cassandra simply runs into a timeout.

You can change the timeout, but it isn't a good solution. (For one time it's fine but don't use it in your regular queries.)

There's a better solution: make your client count your rows. You can create a java app where you count your rows, when you inserting them, and insert the result using a counter column in a Cassandra table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy to avoid cassandra timeout usually happens on count(*)

use this bash

`cqlsh -e "copy keyspace.table_name (first_partition_key_name) to '/dev/null'" | sed -n 5p | sed 's/ .*//'`

Answer (score 0):

You can define timeout seconds as a command line option while using Datastax cqlsh. The default value is 10.

```
$ cqlsh --request-timeout=3600
```